# Shutdown takes 10 minutes when swap is enabled

Tags: 15.04, 14.10, 15.10

For over a year now, I have a problem with shutdown. Here are the conditions that need to be met:

- Swap is enabled
- Swap is used: I have 8GB and when I start using above 4~5GB, I start seeing stuff in swap. Usually happens when I run virtual machines or big games.

In these cases, when I shutdown the PC, I see the following:

- Most of the shutdown takes place
- Do nothing for minutes, even 10 minutes or more
- Finally shutdown

Of course, at this point I [use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/a/36717/31099) to sync, mount read only and force shutdown.

With swap disabled, I don't have this problem, but I can run out of memory (which hangs Linux for a minute before OOM makes up its mind to kill someone, which is another problem).

Does anyone know what the problem could be? Or how I can debug it?

I tried [taking the stack trace](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysrq.txt) with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>, but during shutdown the resolution is low and with four cores, most of the trace is outside the screen, so I can't seem to figure out where it is stalling either.

---

P.S. I am not sure if I was affected by this in 14.04, but I'm fairly certain it happened before systemd as well as after it.

---

**Edit:**

Silly me, I can scroll back and see the shutdown logs. If I print a stack trace when shutdown gets stuck, three cores are in `cupidle_enter_state()` or something like that, and the thread printing the stack trace has this trace:

[image: Part 2]

[image: Part 1]

---

**Edit:**

I thought about doing a `swapoff` before shutdown, so that perhaps the problem goes away. This showed that the swap is turned off at a super-slow rate of 8MB/s. This may be why the shutdown was so slow in the first place, perhaps it was doing a `swapoff`. [`swapoff` being slow seems to affect many people](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45673/41313). I'll investigate more and write an answer if I can manage to get something conclusive.

Comment: Just FYI, a few months ago I did a clean install of 16.04 in my new shiny SSD and I don't have this problem anymore. Not sure if the problem went away because of using a new kernel, or because of clean reinstall.